# python spacy How to visulaize all the spans of a doc

Tags: python, spacy

Following instructions of Spacy documentation I find that:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.tokens import Span

text = "Welcome to the Bank of China. We are at home."

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp(text)

doc.spans["sc"] = [
    Span(doc, 3, 6, "ORG"), 
    Span(doc, 5, 6, "GPE"),
]

doc.spans["custom"] = [Span(doc, 9, 10, "home")]
options = {"spans_key": "custom"}
displacy.serve(doc, style="span", options=options)
```

How do I need to define the options in order to display ALL the possible available spans of the doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only display spans under one `spans_key` at a time. If you want to display all spans, you can copy all the spans to a single key and display that key.

Comment: Thats a good one. just call that spans dict "span_visualizer". cool idea.